# Analysing wave header

Tags: c++, qt, audio, encoding

To play my test wave file, I set the following format `fmt`:

```
fmt.setChannelCount(2);
fmt.setCodec("audio/pcm");
fmt.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
fmt.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
fmt.setSampleRate(44100);
fmt.setSampleSize(16);
```

It also works with these settings:

```
fmt.setSampleRate(22050);
fmt.setSampleSize(32);
```

Those settings are meant for a QAudioOutput:

```
player = new QAudioOutput(fmt);
file = new QFile(fileName);
file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
player->start(file);
```

With this setting I can play my test wave file correctly.

But I want to detect the format's settings by reading the header.

I analyse it, it says:

```
Opening WAV file at:  "C:/Deep Purple - Anthology (Disc 2) - 09 - Hold On.wav" 
The size of the WAV file is:  53994908 
WAV File Header read: 
File Type:  "RIFFWAVE" 
File Size:  53994900 
WAV Marker:  "WAVE" 
Format Name:  "fmt??(" 
Format Length:  4128 
Format Type:  256 
Number of Channels:  512 
Sample Rate:  11289600 
Sample Rate * Bits/Sample * Channels / 8:  45158400 
Bits per Sample * Channels / 8.1:  1024 
Bits per Sample:  4096 
Data Header:  "" 
Data Size:  937783393
```

If I divide the sample rate by the number of channels, I get a sample rate per channel of 22050. But why do I have to set 44100 to make it sound good? And why are there 512 channels? Opening the file with Audacity, there are only 2 (Audacity says: Stereo, 44100Hz, 32-bit float).

Comment: The way you are analyzing it is garbling it. How are you analyzing it?

Comment: I dont know what garbling is. I mean i detect the audio's sample rate and such things. by reading the header according to the Riff WAV specs.

Comment: However you are reading the header, it is causing the bytes to be offset. (`512` is `2` with an extra byte...`11289600` is `44100` with an extra byte...) How are you reading the header?

Comment: I did use this code for my first attempt: http://www.ptrackapp.com/apclassys-notes/qt-c-wav-file-reader/

Answer (score 0):

Here are a bunch of links that helped me out a ton when I was working on this kind of a project.

https://github.com/visore/QAudioCoder

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6899

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-maemo/demos-spectrum-app-wavfile-cpp.html

http://fledisplace.com/QtMultimediaExample2.html

I did find a typo in one of the examples, it wasn't reading one of the parameters with the correct endianness. Let me double check which one it was, and I'll get back to you.

Hope that helps.